# Laravel Input Facade vs Request Facade

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-facade

Based on [Input Facade API](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Input.html) and [Request Facade API](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Request.html) the Input::get() method seems to be the only difference. Am I missing something here?

I know Validation can be applied to Requests, but I am not sure if the same is true for the Input facade.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes both Facades are very similar. The reason for this is that the underlying class is the same (`Illuminate\Http\Request`). You can see this by looking at both Facade classes and their accessors:

`Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input`

```
protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
{
    return 'request';
}
```

`Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request`

```
protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
{
    return 'request';
}
```

---

As you realized, one difference is the `Input::get()` method. This is just "translated" to `Request::input()` directly in the Facade:

```
public static function get($key = null, $default = null)
{
    return static::$app['request']->input($key, $default);
}
```

---

#### Conclusion

They are essentially the same. That means, there's no need to change your existing code. However if you wanted to it wouldn't make any difference.

When writing new code you should use `Request` facade, and maybe use `Request::input(...)` instead of `Request::get(...)` (because the former supports dot notation to access nested data, like `$name = $request->input('products.0.name');`, but `get` is little faster to be fair).

> `Input` is mentioned nowhere in the documentation for 5.0. It's not (officially) deprecated but the use of `Request` is encouraged.

What I also really like about `Request` is that the Facade actually has the name of the underlying class. This way it's clear what you're dealing with. However this can also be the root of errors. If you use something like `Request::input('name')` make sure to import the Facade with `use Request;` or `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request` and **not** `use Illuminate\Http\Request`. The opposite applies for dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer my question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746675/differences-between-request-classes