# Using $input->all() instead of Input::all() Laravel-5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use `$input->all()` as opposed to `Input::all()` in Laravel-5, however it doesn't seem to like it, even though I am passing the Input reference to the function, like so:

```
/**
 * Search for a specified resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function search(Booking $booking, Input $input)
{
    dd($input->all()); // this doesn't work

    dd(Input::all()); // this DOES work

}
```

The error I get is:

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::all()`

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you're supposed to inject Facades into your Controllers. `Input` is a facade for `Illuminate\Http\Request` and it's service container binding is `request`. So according to the documentation, in Laravel 5 you can do `Request::all()` and in Laravel 5.1 you can do `$request->all()`

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#retrieving-input
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#retrieving-input

EDIT: This post gives some more in-depth information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29961400/2433843

EDIT3: I think it would be great if someone could explain WHY exactly you can't inject Facades into your Controllers. I understand DI and Facades are two different things entirely, and L5+ is pushing the developers towards DI. I just don't exactly understand why injecting a facade wouldn't work, since it points towards another class, and it works when you do not inject it. Not to forget Facades and Aliases are two seperate things too. I hope someone can elaborate on this.

Answer (score 1):

One more important thing about using **Request** or **Input** to access the User Input is the version of Laravel that you are using.

In the Laravel 4.2 and prior, you could have access the **Input::all()**, **Input::get()** but from Laravel 5 onwards, it's been suggested to use the Input via **Request** facade

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests

In case if you want to make use of **Input** in Laravel 5.0 and onwards, then you need to add this facade in the **config/app.php** file under the **aliases** section as **'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class**

Once you add the facade under alias, you should start using the 'Input::all()'

Hope this helps some others, who are having the confusion as whether to use 'Input' or 'Request' for Laravel 5.0 onwards.